# NamedBasicTypeImpl EntityValuedModelPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have code like this in JPQL and Spring Data JPA

```
    @Query("SELECT bt FROM Textmessage t " +
           "JOIN bt.hashtags h " +
           "JOIN h.tag t " +
           "JOIN t.type tt " +
           "WHERE t= :mainTag " +
           "GROUP BY bt " +
           "ORDER BY " +
           "   SUM(CASE WHEN t IN :questionTags THEN tt.weight ELSE 0 END) DESC")
    List<BotreaderTextmessage> findAnswers(
            @Param("mainTag") Tag mainTag,
            @Param("questionTags") List<Tag> questionTags
    );
```

but when i run the query this exception has happend

> class org.hibernate.type.internal.NamedBasicTypeImpl cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart (org.hibernate.type.internal.NamedBasicTypeImpl and org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.EntityValuedModelPart are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I tested the code without the 'order by' condition and without 'case,' and it works well. However, when I add this code, the above error is displayed to me.

I even wrote the query as follows, which might result in different output and query, but it still gave me the above error.

```
    @Query("SELECT bt, " +
           "CASE WHEN bttag IN :tags THEN (SELECT SUM(bttagtype.weight) FROM Textmessage btq " +
                                         "JOIN btq.Hashtags bthq " +
                                         "JOIN bthq.tag bttagq " +
                                         "JOIN bttagq.type bttagtype " +
                                         "WHERE btq.id = bt.id) ELSE 0 END AS tagWeight " +
           "FROM Textmessage bt " +
           "LEFT JOIN bt.hashtags bth " +
           "LEFT JOIN bth.tag bttag " +
           "ORDER BY tagWeight DESC")
    List<Object[]> findAnswerMessagesByChatIdOrderedByTagWeight(
            @Param("tags") List<BotreaderTag> tags);
```